# Why does image style blocks another image?

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

I am working on a website and trying to add a background image for the site. I decided this after adding a picture. The picture shows but the background image doesn't. I started messing around and when I comment out the style for the image, the background image will appear. I would like to keep the styles and have the background image show as well.

So `.home-image` shows, but the style for it, is blocked out when the `background-image` for `#wrapper` appears.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```css
.feature-review-border {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #d83c12;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.feature-review-holder1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: #f4b183;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 9px;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-image {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
}

#wrapper {
  background-image: url(images/tire.png);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1 class="text-format">Car Reviewer</h1>
    </header>

    <nav class="text-format">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="about.html">About</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
      <h2 class="text-format">Featured Reviews</h2>

      <!-- MAKING OF THE FEATURED REVIEWS IMAGES -->
      <!-- BORDER OF FEATURED REVIEWS ON HOME PAGE -->
      <div class="feature-review-border">

        <figure>
          <!-- IMAGE CONTAINER -->
          <div class="feature-review-holder1">
            <img src="images/f150.png" alt="Ford F-150" class="home-image">

            <figcaption>"The hands free options are easy to use and I use the bluetooth connectivity to play music and make phone calls" - Bob
            </figcaption>
          </div>
          <!-- END 'FEATURE-REVIEW-HOLDER' -->

        </figure>

      </div>
```

Comment: Sorry all. I was working on this again and saw an extra curly brace. I deleted it, saved the page and refreshed chrome. Background image pops up. I noticed it when making this questions, but thought nothing of it at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your image path isn't correct. Try to use the relative path for example:

```
#wrapper    {
   background-image:url(./images/tire.png);
}
```

Here's also a working example with a dummy image:

```css
.feature-review-border  {
  max-width:500px;
  padding:7px;
  background-color:#d83c12;
  margin:15px auto;
  border-radius:9px;
}

.feature-review-holder1 {
  width:500px;
  height:380px;
  background-color:#f4b183;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:9px;
  text-align:center;
}

.home-image {
  height:250px;
  width:400px;
}

#wrapper    {
  background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1 class="text-format">Car Reviewer</h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="text-format">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="about.html">About</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h2 class="text-format">Featured Reviews</h2>
        <div class="feature-review-border">
            <figure>
                <!-- IMAGE CONTAINER -->
                <div class="feature-review-holder1">
                    <img src="images/f150.png" alt="Ford F-150" class="home-image">

                    <figcaption>"The hands free options are easy to use and I use the bluetooth connectivity to play music and make phone calls" - Bob
                    </figcaption>
                </div>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe my image path is correct since when the styles for the truck are commented out which is .home-image the background image appears. I also went and tried out your suggestion using the relative path. I copied it and that also did not work.

Comment: Do you have a live site where we can take a look and check it? Maybe you need the path to your wordpress theme -> background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/themeNameHere/images/tire.png ");

Answer (score 0):

You will not see the mistake in the code I added when first asking the question. While making the question I added the code and saw an extra curly brace in the CSS. I thought nothing of it and just deleted it.

Looking over my code today I noticed it and wondered why it was there. I deleted it, saved the page, and then refreshed Chrome. Boom, my background image popped up.

Sorry for all the extra work I caused you. Definitely a lesson I had to learn.

Thanks all for your help.

UPDATE:

I recreated the code with the mistake to show

```
    /* CAPTION OF IMAGE */
figcaption  {
font-family:calibri;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:italic;
font-size:26px;
padding:0px 15px;
```

}

} this should be deleted

```
#wrapper    {
background-image:url(images/tire.png);
```

}